# In Extension:Thanks, is it possible to show the number of 'Thanks' a comment received besides the 'Thank' link?

Tags: mediawiki

Extension:Thanks produces a 'thanks' link beside each comment in StructuredDiscussions a.k.a Flow.
Is it possible to show the number of 'Thanks' a comment received besides the 'Thank' link?

Through some changes in the code, how can the number of 'thanks' be stored in a variable or in the database and can be displayed for each comment?

Answer (score 0):

By default MediaWiki setting, The simplest answer will be **No**. The SQL table which stores the data about the thanks is "logging". And this table Unfourtantly doesn't store any pieces of information about the comment, or the edit. It only stores the name of the user who thanks, the name of the user who made the edit and the timestamp of thank operation. So there is no any info about the name of the page, or the revision_id or what so. See [this link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Logging_table) for more info about the table.